# How to run python without including ~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages in its module search path

Tags: python, anaconda

I have some packages installed under my `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` subdir, which was for use with system python (/usr/bin/python). Now I have just installed Anaconda python (which is also python 2.7, but minor version 11). The whole idea of Anaconda distro is to have a self-containing python environment, such that EVERY module resides within anaconda install tree.

But what annoys me is that for some reason I cannot disable inclusion of `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` from sys.path although I did not have `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Is it possible to run python executable (in this case, Anaconda's python executable) without having to implicitly add `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and the eggs underneath it in the python search path?

Why this problem? Unfortunately the `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth` also contains a reference to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, which causes this system-wide dist-packages to still be searched for.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a `-s` flag in python executable to disable searching the user site directory (`~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages etc). That solves the problem above!