# anaconda3 includes user's local site-packages to path

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

Installed anaconda (v 5.1.0) and saw that sys.path includes my system-python
libraries too, placed in ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ by default,
without me adding anything to the python path in spyder.

According to [How to run python without including ~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages in its module search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129077/how-to-run-python-without-including-local-lib-pythonx-y-site-packages-in-its), this is a feature of python that can be fixed by running 'python3 -s' instead of just 'python3', but how do you tell spyder to run python with option -s?
This is the question!

The problem is having other versions of the same libs in ~/.local/... for
some py3 packages outside the anaconda-environment and i think spyder itself is getting confused. And anaconda would not be a separate python environment on its own in this case.

If spyder ran 'python3 -s', then i could place myself folders in the anaconda-env path by using spyder's

```
Tools -> PYTHONPATH manager...
```

if i wanted to.

Comment: This is a feature of Python more broadly, nothing to do with Anaconda specifically. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38129077/2449192

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run python without including ~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages in its module search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129077/how-to-run-python-without-including-local-lib-pythonx-y-site-packages-in-its)

Comment: thank you @darthbith  that explains much of what is happening, but how do i tell spyder to run 'python -s' instead of 'python'? I will edit to mention your related link and the question that still stands.

Comment: Have you tried `spyder -s`? or `spyder --help`?

Comment: @darthbith , i only tried the various customization/options windows from within spyder, and the documentation about command line options at  https://docs.spyder-ide.org/options.html  does not show an '-s' option or anything that seems related (and 'spyder --help' in my installation shows the same thing).